# 100vh and mobile responsive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport-units

I want to build a responsive website for mobile. How do I stay in control of my height, when building pixel-perfect pages?

As you might be aware, viewport units are not supported on mobile browsers, it is a known issue.

- I cannot use `vw` or `vh` because they are not supported
- I cannot use `%` because I would need to set height for the parent element
- I cannot use `px` or any static units, because I am building a responsive design

I've put something together so you get a better idea:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#page1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#top {
  height: 30%;
  background: #ddd;
}

#bottom {
  height: 70%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#page2 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#page3 {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page1">
    <div id="top">This is the top of page1. Its height should be 30% of 100vh
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">This is the bottom part of page1. Its height should be 70% of 100vh</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page2"> This is page 2 and is also 100vh high</div>
  <div id="page3"> This is page 3 and is also 100vh high</div>
</body>
```

Now that would be completely fine on PC but on mobile, it gets jumpy when address bar hides/shows and that is not acceptable.

So any alternatives for `vh` unit?

Thanks, Eidan

Answer (score 2):

Vw and Vh ARE supported. You just need to add this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yes I do use all meta tags I just havent included them in the example. Here are some more details about the issue: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832

Comment: I think you can do it with javascript, look here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing

Comment: It still is not the behavior you would expect + its only Chrome so its hardly usable for real life production (still have other browsers + iOS to worry about). I have read that you can do it with JS but haven't found any working solution yet.

Comment: Also, when you want an element to occupy say 30% of your vh, when the URL bar dissapears it also changes the height of that element.. Its really frustrating...

Comment: I know that there are techniques to hide url bar on IOS but I have never succeeded on Android ..
There are also libraries to switch to full screen but I have never tested https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Answer (score 0):

CSS units vh and vw are supported, but on mobile the address bar is the problem. When you use for root element height: 100vh, bottom of this element is out of viewport. My solution:

1.) on resize event set for root div style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
this make you root div fully visible, but address bar takes up a lot of space (especially on landscape orientation)

2.) CSS: body: {height: 150vh} and root element: {position: fixed}
this allow "fake" scrolling and user can hide or show address bar  and content of root element adapts, when size is changed.